# Vue custom directive does not have 'this' context / this is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I attempted to create a basic Vue directive, and had an issue accessing `this`. I'm not using arrow functions in this case, and have taken an example straight from the [Vue documentation](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html), and am still experiencing this issue.

Reproducible: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-lichterman-forud

Vue: v2.6.11

Directive:

```js
// When bound produces `undefined` from console.log
// I've tried placing this in main.js / App.vue
Vue.directive("example", {
  twoWay: true, // I've tried setting this false / true
  bind: function() {
    console.log(this);
  },
  unbind: function() {
    console.log("unbind", this);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the `v0.12` docs, but your example uses the current version of Vue (`v2.6.11`). From the [2.x docs for bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments), the API for `bind` is different:

```js
Vue.directive('demo', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    var s = JSON.stringify
    el.innerHTML =
      'name: '       + s(binding.name) + '<br>' +
      'value: '      + s(binding.value) + '<br>' +
      'expression: ' + s(binding.expression) + '<br>' +
      'argument: '   + s(binding.arg) + '<br>' +
      'modifiers: '  + s(binding.modifiers) + '<br>' +
      'vnode keys: ' + Object.keys(vnode).join(', ')
  }
})
```

In 2.x, the data that was accessible through `this` is now passed as hook arguments (i.e., `el`, `binding`, and `vnode`). Also, `twoWay` no longer exists in 2.x, as you could use [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) without specifying any props.

[updated Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-dream-2fbjm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info! I really thought I was checking out v2 docks, I must have been mistaken. Thanks!